TS2345: Argument of type 'string \| string[] \| ParsedQs \| ParsedQs[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'
I have following exception:
permissions.controller.ts(35,51): error TS2345: Argument of type 'string \| string[] \| ParsedQs \| ParsedQs[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
--
293 | #12 11.89   Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
294 | #12 11.89 permissions.controller.ts(36,85): error TS2345: Argument of type 'string \| string[] \| ParsedQs \| ParsedQs[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
295 | #12 11.89 permissions.controller.ts(37,80): error TS2345: Argument of type 'string \| string[] \| ParsedQs \| ParsedQs[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
296 | #12 11.89 permissions.controller.ts(38,80): error TS2345: Argument of type 'string \| string[] \| ParsedQs \| ParsedQs[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

Below is the code
export async function getPermissions(request: RequestWithAuth, response: Response) {
  const titleCode = request.user?.user?.data?.titleCode;
  const email = request.user?.user?.email ? request.user?.user?.email.toLowerCase() : '';
  const storeId = request?.query?.storeId;
  const user: UserRequestObj = request;

  // if (_.isNil(titleCode)) {
  //   response.json(defaultResult);
  //   return;
  // }

  const result = {
    chatAccess:
      hardCodedAdmins.has(email) ||
      adminTitleCodes.has(titleCode) ||
      chatAccessEmails.has(email) ||
      chatAccessTitleCodes.has(titleCode) ||
      chatAccessToAllSDs(titleCode),
    isManager: managerTitleCodes.has(titleCode) || adminTitleCodes.has(titleCode) || hardCodedAdmins.has(email),
    ...(await sosAccess.getPermissions(titleCode, storeId, user, hardCodedAdmins)),
    ...(await performancePayAccess.getPermissions(titleCode, user, hardCodedAdmins, storeId)),
    ...(await whReturnsAccess.getPermissions(titleCode, user, hardCodedAdmins, storeId)),
    ...(await manifestsAccess.getPermissions(titleCode, user, hardCodedAdmins, storeId))
  };
  response.json(result);
}

"@types/express": "4.16.1",
"@types/qs": "6.9.14",
"@types/request": "2.48.3",
"typescript": "5.3.3",
nodejs: 18
Please advise on how to resolve this issue.
